# Аналог срезов(Slices) в python в C#

Tags: c#, строки

Господа, возник вот какой вопрос, как перенести одно слово в строке на место другого, например

```
            Вход: "Hello world"
            Выход: "world Hello"
```

Для особо умных: массивами пользоваться нельзя. На вход поступает только одна строка, а на выход уже переделанная.

Comment: Хамите, парниша (© Щукина Э.). Не с того начинаете свою деятельность на SO...

Comment: Ну ведь интерес не заглушишь ничем, тем более на таком языке как C#.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать например так:

```
var str = "Hello world";
str = string.Join(" ", str.Split(' ').Reverse());
```

Comment: Благодарю, именно этого я хотел.

Answer (score 0):

При чём тут срезы?

Разделить строку на массив слов с помощью `split`, затем собрать в другом порядке. Если в массиве переставить элементы в нужном порядке, то достаточно `join`

Comment: А как без массива?

Comment: @gdubroff, а в этом вашем питоне срезы не с массивами работают?

Comment: В олимпиадных задачах нельзя пользоваться массивами.